# How do I prove the significance of a non-linear model?

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, nonlinear-regression

For example, for linear models, you take the p-value of the regression, and you deduce if the regression is or not significative. But with non linear models, in R, there isn't shown a p-value associated to a F-statistic, that say if the regression is or not significative. How can I know if a non linear model is significative? What tools can I use in R for that?

Comment: `anova(nullmodel,fullmodel)` should work, for whatever you might regard as a null model in your problem

Answer (score 1):

You could do tests based on Likelihood Ratio, which you can get from the log likelihoods of your baseline and alternative - models.

Generally there are Walds test, Likelihood Ratio - test and Lagrange Multiplier - test (Score) for non-linear and linear models.

Your R output will contain values for the maximized log-likelihood, you can use these as an input vector for your test.

And for individual coefficients almost all functions producing maximum likelihood based estimates will produce also z-values. And from these z-values you can deduct their statistical significance.